# I want to make fullcalendar with codeigniter,,but somehow I encounter this error

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

I encounter this error. Please help me if you know the solution

> Severity: Error
>   Message: Call to undefined function form_open()
>   Filename: views/index.php
>   Line Number: 33

1. index.php (view)

   Calendar Display

   ```
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" />
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
       <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/fullcalendar-3.9.0/locale/es.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>

   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">

   <h1>Calendar</h1>

   <div id="calendar">

       <div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Calendar Event</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
             <?php echo form_open(site_url('calendar/add_event'), array("class" => "form-horizontal")) ?>
             <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading">Event Name</label>
                       <div class="col-md-8 ui-front">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="">
                       </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading">Description</label>
                       <div class="col-md-8 ui-front">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description">
                       </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading">Start Date</label>
                       <div class="col-md-8">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="start_date">
                       </div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="p-in" class="col-md-4 label-heading">End Date</label>
                       <div class="col-md-8">
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end_date">
                       </div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Event">
               <?php echo form_close() ?>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>



   <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
       var date_last_clicked + null;
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

          eventSources: [
            {
                events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>calendar/get_events',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: start.unix(),
                    end: end.unix()
                    },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var events = msg.events;
                        callback(events);
                    }
                    });
                }
            },
        ]
                    dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                       date_last_clicked = $(this);
                       $(this).css('background-color', '#bed7f3');
                       $('#addModal').modal();
                       },            

       });
       });
   </script>
   <style>
           #calendar{
               width: 800px;
               margin: 0px auto;
           }
   </style>


   </body>
   ```
2. Calendar.php (controller)

   ```
   class Calendar extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model("calendar_model");
   }

   public function index()
   {
       $this->load->helper('url');
       $this->load->view('index', array());
   }

    public function get_events()
    {
        // Our Start and End Dates
        $start = $this->input->get('start');
        $end = $this->input->get('end');

        $startdt = new DateTime('now'); // setup a local datetime
        $startdt->setTimestamp($start); // Set the date based on timestamp
        $start_format = $startdt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $enddt = new DateTime('now'); // setup a local datetime
        $enddt->setTimestamp($end); // Set the date based on timestamp
        $end_format = $enddt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $events = $this->calendar_model->get_events($start_format, $end_format);

        $data_events = array();

        foreach($events->result() as $r) {

            $data_events[] = array(
                "id" => $r->ID,
                "title" => $r->title,
                "description" => $r->description,
                "end" => $r->end,
                "start" => $r->start
            );
        }

        echo json_encode(array("events" => $data_events));
        exit();
    }

    public function add_event() 
   {
       /* Our calendar data */
       $name = $this->input->post("name", TRUE);
       $desc = $this->input->post("description", TRUE);
       $start_date = $this->input->post("start_date", TRUE);
       $end_date = $this->input->post("end_date", TRUE);

       if(!empty($start_date)) {
          $sd = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d H:i", $start_date);
          $start_date = $sd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $start_date_timestamp = $sd->getTimestamp();
       } else {
          $start_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
          $start_date_timestamp = time();
       }

       if(!empty($end_date)) {
          $ed = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y/m/d H:i", $end_date);
          $end_date = $ed->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $end_date_timestamp = $ed->getTimestamp();
       } else {
          $end_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
          $end_date_timestamp = time();
       }

       $this->calendar_model->add_event(array(
          "title" => $name,
          "description" => $desc,
          "start" => $start_date,
          "end" => $end_date
          )
       );

       redirect(site_url("calendar"));
   }
   ```

   }
3. Calendar_model.php (model)

   ```
   class Calendar_model extends CI_Model {

   public function get_events($start, $end){

       return $this->db->where("start >=", $start)->where("end <=", $end)->get('calendar_events');
   }

   public function add_event($data)
   {
       $this->db->insert('calendar_events', $data);
   }

   public function get_event($id)
   {
       return $this->db->where("ID", $id)->get('calendar_events');
   }

   public function update_event($id, $data)
   {
       $this->db->where("ID", $id)->update('calendar_events', $data);
   }

   public function delete_event($id)
   {
       $this->db->where("ID", $id)->delete('calendar_events');
   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML it seems there is a markup issue. But anyway you need to make sure that the Form helper and URL helpers are both loaded in the function you want to use.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('index', array());
}
```